# Posting a photo as an open graph facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application that has many open graph pages. I'm able to post as these pages just fine, except for photos. I get a "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource." which makes no sense because I can post to the feed as the page no problem.

Heres the code:

```
require_once ('facebook.php');

$fb = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'XXX',
'secret' => 'XXX',
));  

$fb->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
$args['image'] = '@' . realpath("testpic.jpg");

$data = $fb->api("/PAGEID/photos", "post", $args);

print_r($data);
?>
```

Is this possible to do without needing a user to login? I read that you can request the page access_token as a user, but it seems kind of dumb that you can use one way of authenticating for one function, then another way for another. I'd like to avoid an user logins if possible.

Comment: Submitted a bug too https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/371884269549068

Answer (score 0):

The app posting the photo needs to include in $args an access token for admin'ing the page. This is also called a "page access token" or "page token".

```
$args['access_token'] = $access_token;
```

The way I get such an access token is to obtain `manage_pages,publish_stream` permissions from the user (me) who is an admin of the page.  Then:

```
$page_info = $facebook->api('/'.$PAGE_ID.'?fields=access_token');
```

and:

```
$access_token = $page_info['access_token'];
```

See also: [Developer blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/524/)

Comment: I don't want to (nor should I have to) get a user token if I'm already authorizing as an app.

Comment: In my example, I'm not using a user token, but a page token.  I've edited my answer to clarify this. This is also in the blog post referenced in my answer.  Basically, I pass a page token that is allowed manage_pages and publish_stream.  Did you submit the token you are using to the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)?  What permissions did the debugger say it has?

Comment: What doesn't make sense is I can post to a Facebook page as the application that page is associated to without user access token like in your example, but for photos that doesn't work. It's an inconsistency in Facebook's API.